# ios turn based game debugging and development with Game Center

Tags: ios, game-center

I am developing a turn based game for ios devices. However, when i create a match in game center by using simulator , i cannot retrieve the match in my device. i cannot set up the way to debug my game. Could you guys please give me some advices to develop with game center? 1 simulator and 1 device with 2 testing accounts is that good enough?

thanks for your advices

justicepenny

Answer (score -1):

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/TestingYourGameCenter-AwareGame/TestingYourGameCenter-AwareGame.html Look at this document (especially bottom of page).

"Leaderboards and achievements work the same way in Simulator as they do on a device. However, matchmaking invitations may not be sent or received while your game is running in Simulator." That's true it depends on the version of Xcode that you're using and several things. But try the "Play Now" selection on the Game Center MatchMaker UI. It generally works fine. But the invitations are generally an irritating problem with Simulator. Hope it helps.